# How to create superuser account in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know how do I recover a superuser account in postgresql.

I accidentally unchecked the superuser privilege of my local `postgres` account.  It was the only superuser account at this postgresql instance.

Now I cannot login to my local server.

I tried it using:

```
#psql -U postgres
```

but it did not work.

Could you help me with the problem and kindly provide me with detailed solution to my problem?

Comment: You need to start postgresql in single user mode: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61784/134557

Comment: i use windows 7 os

Comment: That works for all operating systems.

Comment: Do you have it as service on win 7?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: That is not really true.  How do you run `service postgresql stop` when there is no postgresql service?

Comment: i stop postgresql service using windows services interface, but then what will i do next?

Comment: Yes, ok, you have to use backslashes in the paths and stopping the server is different everywhere. I had assumed that it is known how to stop the PostgreSQL server.

Comment: ok i already stop the postgresql service

Comment: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin>psql -u postgres postgres

Comment: i tried this one but the result is pgsql: illegal option -- u

Comment: Please move the question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/. It is not programming-related.

Answer (score 4):

You have do this from shell:

1. First change your user to `postgres` one:    `> su - postgres`
2. Get into postres run-> `> psql`
3. Inside postgres run this sql query: `ALTER USER postgres WITH SUPERUSER;`
4. To view the permissions on the user run: `\du`

For future reference you check the [Alter user documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alteruser.html).

**First Edit** - good point by  Łukasz Kamiński

You have to run it in single mode as pointed in the [account on postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61781/restoring-the-superuser-account-on-the-postgres-server/61784#61784) (credits to Łukasz Kamiński for pasting the link).

If you are on windows you can not run the commands in the link as they are meant to be run on *nix environment (namely on debian or clone at this link).

On windows you have to:

1. stop services via `run` -> `services.msc` and find the service
   (can be also done via `net stop <exact name of the service>` at command line)
2. then start your `cmd.exe` (as administrator -> not required anymore from PG9.6 even a blocker - thank you  Łukasz Kamiński)
3. find your `postgres` executable e.g. `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10.0\bin> postgres.exe --single -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10.0\data"`
4. Run the `ALTER USER postgres WITH SUPERUSER;` to have the super user again.
5. start via `run` -> `services.msc` and find the service (can be also done via `net start <exact name of the service>` at command line)

Comment: If he revoked superuser from postgres, then he can't revert that change in normally running server, since you need to be superuser in order to grant superuser privilege.

Comment: True.  I has to be done only with other superuser.  If not he has to do it in single user mode (actually similar to linux single user mode :) )

Comment: yeah, i cannot do any alteration because i need to login first using a superuser account and that thing was my problem

Comment: Don't run cmd as administrator, it will likely complain about security issues and that you need to start it as normal user. I managed to give superuser to postgres with just my normal system account. Also, it is good idea to specify database that you want to use, since it defaults to the same as your current OS username - just put its name at the end of command used to run server. Data folder could also be in different place (my install has it at `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\data\pg96`)

Comment: so in my command prompt the exact line is C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin>postgres.exe --single -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data"

Comment: Now execute the `ALTER USER postgres WITH SUPERUSER;`  @ŁukaszKamiński: I agree to your points.  With the administrator priv. on windows it is always tricky and you have to reflect your instance (testing, dev, production etc).  For the DB name, yes, but I think he has only one DB name, would you like me to improve the answer then?

Comment: @tukan for me, PG9.6 outright refused to start when I attempted to do so with admin cmd.exe. It could be different for older installs like 9.2. As for DB name - it won't matter in this case (since he is altering server wide role), but if that database does not exist then he won't be able to start server. For example I don't have on my localhost database named `lkaminski`.

Comment: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin>postgres.exe --single -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data" is this correct?this is the line in my command promt

Comment: find your postgres executable e.g. c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10.0\bin> postgres.exe --single -D "c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10.0\data" this part, where should i find it?in windows folder explorer or in cmd?

Comment: This everything should be executed in the `cmd.exe` alias command prompt

Comment: ok so C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin>postgres.exe --single -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data" is this correct?this is the line in my command prompt

Comment: yes, if that is where your postresql instance which you are trying to fixed is installed.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński: good to see they got rid of the cmd admin requirement.  Of course you don't have lkaminsky DB that would be weird.  I assumed he is looking for default user recovery and did not consider he is trying to specify the database.  Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński: `postgres.exe` will indeed refuse to start as Administrator, but `pg_ctl` will not (it will start `postgres.exe` without the elevated privileges) That's one of the reasons why it's better to use `pg_ctl` instead of `postgres`

Comment: this is what happen.

previously my server is working fine. for so long i already created databases on it, but last monday i open the properties of postgres account and take note that is the only account i have on my server, the i go to privileges tab then i uncheck the superuser checkbox then answer the question by yes the i accidentally click ok button which is it apply the changes already, the i click refresh button the suddenly i was logout on my server after i click refresh button, then i cannot login already using the same account postgres username

Comment: @kelvinroco when the answer helps you please accept it - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @kelvinroco so are you missing something?  Does not work?